# The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?' in null safety

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: _buildAppBar(),
)
```

Here's the function:

```dart
Widget _buildAppBar() => AppBar(); // Error
```

This code was working fine until I migrated my code to null safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart null safety doesn't allow downcasting, so you can't assign a `Widget` to `PreferredSizeWidget` just like you can't assign an `Object` to a `String` (which was possible before null safety).

You should change your function and return `AppBar` or `PreferredSizeWidget` from it.

```dart
AppBar _buildAppBar() => AppBar();
```

or

```dart
PreferredSizeWidget _buildAppBar() => AppBar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but the answer from iDecode is correct

```
AppBar customAppBar(String title, bool centerTitle, List<Widget> actions) {}
```

whit this the error is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: _buildAppBar() as PreferredSizeWidget?,
)
```